# Como usar o recurso Pagination do Laravel com queries no formato raw DB::select()

Tags: laravel, select, paginação

Para obter algumas informações do banco de dados em alguns momentos é mais simples fazer uma querie com sql cru do que usar vários modelos, funções maps e um toque de mágica para chegar ao mesmo objetivo, porém o problema de usar uma querie cru ou uma [expressão raw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions) com fácilidade temos que usar a função `DB::select()` e exatamente essa fácilidade que cria um problema que o retorno dos dados não é compativel com a função do Laravel chamada paginação ou [Database Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination) que já vem pronta com o framework, no meu caso eu tentei usar da seguinte maneira em meu [controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTES CL, PEDIDOS PD WHERE PD.ID_CLIENTE = CL.ID";

public function obterDados(){
    return DB::select($sql)->simplePaginate(10);
}
```

Então o resultado retornado é o erro abaixo:

`Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
"Call to a member function simplePaginate() on array"`

Então como usar DB::select() com a função pagination do framework Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

A reposta é a seguinte, para usar o método `simplePaginate()` é necessário que minha função `obterDados()` me retorne um objeto [Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html) e não um objeto [array](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php)
porque o é o objeto Builder que contém o método [simplePaginate()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_simplePaginate).

O único meio que eu encontrei para usar a paginação do framework sem alterar a querie SQL foi **criar uma view no banco de dados**. Desta forma eu pude **criar um modelo para acessar essa view**, dessa forma eu consegui resolver meu problema e a função no meu controller ficou assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTES CL, PEDIDOS PD WHERE PD.ID_CLIENTE = CL.ID";

public function obterDados(){
    return ViewPedidosClientes::simplePaginate(15);
}
```